# Mac app icon not displayed in itunes connect

Tags: macos, upload, app-store, app-store-connect

How to add mac app icon in itunes connect ?
Do we need to add the icon image in xcode and then upload the binary ?
Or can we add icon from iTunes itself.

Answer (score 15):

I personally took the risk and submitted my app to Mac App store without seeing the icon on itunes connect. Couple of minutes after the submission, the icon was on the page when I refreshed the page.

Answer (score 6):

Itunesconnect has a bug when submitting desktop app updates no icon is displayed:

[image]

if you submit for review and wait a couple of minutes this should resolve itself.

Comment: Why this yellow warning icon is displayed? I have same issue

Answer (score 1):

The app icon is uploaded with the binary, so it will just grab whatever icon your selected build has.

Comment: Is the icon taken from the images.xcassets file or a .icns? I've tried both methods still to no avail.

Comment: @simonthumper it seemed to be whatever icon Xcode used when valdiating/submitting the binary. But for me it turned out that the icon doesn't show up in iTunes connect until you've submitted it for review

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a couple of page refresh didn't work but when I went **inside the app** and icon appeared there and also appeared on the apps main page when I returned to the apps main page.