# Can't get icon to load on Mac Store from binary

Tags: macos, icons, app-store

So I tried both the old standby - here:

Attempt 1:
[How can I set the icon for a Mac Application in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337787/how-can-i-set-the-icon-for-a-mac-application-in-xcode/12156032#12156032)

Attempt 2:  Also tried the new way, which is filling out the Images.xcassets...

Results: both times in the App Store the icon is greyed out.  Both times the art is shown on the Mac binary .app that's placed in my production folder.

Would sure appreciate an answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Ah found the answer... another post had the solution...

[Mac app icon not displayed in itunes connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376637/mac-app-icon-not-displayed-in-itunes-connect/28398761#28398761)

Looks like iTunes currently has a bug that needs you to submit the app in order to get the icon loaded.  no biggie.